# Volumegroup using entire disks instead of partition - Extending online Vmware

Tags: linux, virtualization, lvm

Is it possible when using entire disk for volume groups to extend the assigned disks space from the vmware console, and then **online** the volume group after rescanning host to know the new size, or to force it know the new size.

e.g i have a disk 200GB and i have used to create the vgcreate entire disk instead of partition, if i resize the disk to 250GB in vmware console and force rescan of scsi_device in guest os(Linux) will that update occur to the volume group or is there a way to make it happen?

Currently i am creating a partition with the maximum and in case of expanding the same disk i create a new partition and use vgextend to make it available.

I am kinda new to lvm so i would appreciate a possible workaround to that.

**This is required to be done without unmounting any partition or the disk**

Completely on-the-fly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is completely fine to add additional disks to the volume group with vgextend. You need all of them for the VG to work of course.

You can force a rescan for the disks in the guest by [echoing values into scsi_host nodes](https://serverfault.com/questions/490397/what-does-in-echo-sys-class-scsi-host-host0-scan-mean)   There should be a message from the kernel in syslog.

I prefer to manage LVM PVs as partitions. parted is a useful tool to do this with its resizepart command. -0 being the end of disk is a convenient for the end of the last partition.

pvresize will extend the PV to use the larger disk. The VG is larger when this succeeds.