# HP Smart Array P812 HBA mode Masked Drives

Tags: ubuntu, hp-smart-array, hba

I have an HP Smart Array P812 card flashed to HBA mode. Kernel patched Linux for this module, Ubuntu 22. Everything was working a week ago, I had passthrough of the drives, I even used them to test the setup and copied files, etc. It worked. Starting two days ago it just wasn't showing up anymore. I rebooted, no change.

Pulled up `ssacli` to check controller and drives, seems like everything is ok, but drives still don't show up on `lsblk`.

```
$ ssacli ctrl all show detail

Smart Array P812 in Slot 4
   Bus Interface: PCI
   Slot: 4
   Serial Number: PAGXQ0ARHZY04W
   Cache Serial Number: PBCDF0CRH0D5U9
   RAID 6 Status: Enabled
   Controller Status: OK
   Hardware Revision: C
   Firmware Version: 3.66
   Firmware Supports Online Firmware Activation: False
   Cache Board Present: True
   Cache Status: Not Configured
   Total Cache Size: 1.0
   Total Cache Memory Available: 0.9
   Battery Backed Cache Size: 0.9
   Cache Backup Power Source: Capacitors
   Battery/Capacitor Count: 1
   Battery/Capacitor Status: OK
   Number of Ports: 6 (2 Internal / 4 External )
   Driver Name: hpsa
   Driver Version: 3.4.20
   WWN Port: 50014380132301B0
   HBA Mode Enabled: True
   PCI Address (Domain:Bus:Device.Function): 0000:42:00.0
   Port Max Phy Rate Limiting Supported: False
   Sanitize Erase Supported: False
   Primary Boot Volume: None
   Secondary Boot Volume: None
   SPDM Supports Get Slot Certificate Chain: no
   SPDM Supports Get Controller Info       : no
   SPDM Supports Get Slot Info             : no
   SPDM Supports Set Import Certificate    : no
   SPDM Supports Set Invalidate Slot       : no
   Surface Scan Completion Supported: False
   Persistent Event Log Policy Change Supported: False

$ cat /proc/scsi/scsi
Attached devices:
Host: scsi1 Channel: 00 Id: 00 Lun: 00
  Vendor: HP       Model: P812             Rev: 3.66
  Type:   RAID                             ANSI  SCSI revision: 05
Host: scsi0 Channel: 00 Id: 00 Lun: 00
  Vendor: SEAGATE  Model: ST3146356SS      Rev: HS0F
  Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI  SCSI revision: 05
Host: scsi0 Channel: 00 Id: 01 Lun: 00
  Vendor: WD       Model: WD3001FYYG-01SL3 Rev: VR07
  Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI  SCSI revision: 06
Host: scsi0 Channel: 00 Id: 02 Lun: 00
  Vendor: WD       Model: WD3001FYYG-01SL3 Rev: VR07
  Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI  SCSI revision: 06
Host: scsi0 Channel: 00 Id: 03 Lun: 00
  Vendor: WD       Model: WD3001FYYG-01SL3 Rev: VR07
  Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI  SCSI revision: 06
Host: scsi0 Channel: 00 Id: 04 Lun: 00
  Vendor: SEAGATE  Model: ST3146356SS      Rev: HS0F
  Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI  SCSI revision: 05
Host: scsi0 Channel: 00 Id: 05 Lun: 00
  Vendor: WD       Model: WD3001FYYG-01SL3 Rev: VR07
  Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI  SCSI revision: 06
Host: scsi0 Channel: 00 Id: 06 Lun: 00
  Vendor: WD       Model: WD3001FYYG-01SL3 Rev: VR07
$ ssacli ctrl slot=4 pd all show detail

Smart Array P812 in Slot 4

   HBA Drives

      physicaldrive 4E:1:1
         Port: 4E
         Box: 1
         Bay: 1
         Status: OK
         Drive Type: HBA Mode Drive
         Interface Type: Solid State SATA
         Size: 2 TB
         Drive exposed to OS: False
         Logical/Physical Block Size: 512/512
         Firmware Revision: U1014A0
         Serial Number: AA202300002100001831
         WWID: 50014380042BA501
         Model: ATA     SSD 2TB
         SATA NCQ Capable: True
         SATA NCQ Enabled: True
         SSD Smart Trip Wearout: Not Supported
         PHY Count: 1
         PHY Transfer Rate: 1.5Gbps
         PHY Physical Link Rate: Unknown
         PHY Maximum Link Rate: Unknown
         Sanitize Erase Supported: False
         Shingled Magnetic Recording Support: None
```

If I check out `dmesg` is knows they are there but they are masked. I've tried re-running `modprobe hbsa` but no change, not to mention it should run that at boot anyways, I rebooted a few times after getting all this to work a few weeks ago with no issues.

```
$ dmesg | grep masked
[    4.554241] hpsa 0000:42:00.0: scsi 1:0:1:0: masked Direct-Access     ATA      SSD 2TB          PHYS DRV SSDSmartPathCap- En- Exp=0
[    4.568580] hpsa 0000:42:00.0: scsi 1:0:2:0: masked Direct-Access     ATA      SSD 2TB          PHYS DRV SSDSmartPathCap- En- Exp=0
[    4.583223] hpsa 0000:42:00.0: scsi 1:0:3:0: masked Direct-Access     ATA      SSD 2TB          PHYS DRV SSDSmartPathCap- En- Exp=0
[    4.597927] hpsa 0000:42:00.0: scsi 1:0:4:0: masked Direct-Access     ATA      SSD 2TB          PHYS DRV SSDSmartPathCap- En- Exp=0
[    4.612871] hpsa 0000:42:00.0: scsi 1:0:5:0: masked Enclosure         HP       MSA70            enclosure SSDSmartPathCap- En- Exp=0
[    4.628075] hpsa 0000:42:00.0: scsi 1:0:6:0: masked Enclosure         HP       P812 INT EXP     enclosure SSDSmartPathCap- En- Exp=0
[    4.643197] hpsa 0000:42:00.0: scsi 1:0:7:0: masked Enclosure         PMCSIERA  SRC 8x6G        enclosure SSDSmartPathCap- En- Exp=0
```

**UPDATE**

Tried clearing config on the drives, it won't let me. I can only imaging because the controller is in HBA mode so it thinks nothing to clear:

```
$ ssacli ctrl slot=4 physicaldrive 4E:1:5 modify clearconfigdata

Error: This operation is not supported with the current configuration. Use the 
       "show" command on devices to show additional details about the
       configuration.
       Reason: Not supported
```

Comment: Have you run [`echo "- - -" > /sys/class/scsi_host/host0/scan`](https://serverfault.com/questions/490397/what-does-in-echo-sys-class-scsi-host-host0-scan-mean) as mentioned in that post to see if the kernel will redetect the masked drivers? I would also be sure to check physical connections to ensure something connection wise did not come disconnected somehow like drive cables. Here's a post that talks about hiding partitions to give you ideas to check as well to ensure is not set: https://askubuntu.com/questions/124094/how-to-hide-an-ntfs-partition-from-ubuntu

Comment: I have, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Well I see your config output indicates link rates are "unknown". I wonder if they are having a hard time negotiating speed or something funny like that. See this post here where it talks about rare configuration bug with sector size mismatch: https://serverfault.com/questions/458804/proliant-server-will-not-accept-new-hard-disks-in-raid-10. I assume you did not swap a drive from the array but ensure your Ubuntu kernel version didn't change or boot into a different default on boot. Consider controller and bios firmware upgrades, kernel upgrades or rollbacks too. Maybe you have a rare case tho.

Comment: Your problem is here: "Drive exposed to OS: False". Controller treats the drive as having some sort of configuration on it and is not passing it to the OS. You can clear the configuration with "ssacli <drive location> modify clearconfigdata".

Comment: Tried that, update above.

Comment: The question is, to be precise, why HBA marks drives as non-exportable to the OS. Thing is, it depends. Please, specify exact firmware revision/custom version you're at, server platform in use (EFI/BIOS version), as well as complete output from `ctrl all show config detail` as well as as `ctrl slot=X pd all show status`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing code bases to the one below:

https://github.com/99dimitris/hpsahba

It seems the original Git code to convert the card to HBA mode, the kernel driver must of had issues. By changing to that codebase above, re-doing my marking my controller as HBA, then re-installing the new DKMS driver with this package worked. After a reboot all my drives worked fine.

Seemed to be a driver issue with the previous codebase.